# Is there a way to prevent a DropDownList from showing list items when clicked in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Just wondering if there is a way with Javascript to prevent the regular click event from happening of a DropDownList. Basically I have a DropDownList that I want to leave enabled, but when it is clicked I don't want the regular list of items to popup. Is there a way to do this at all with like e.preventDefault or something?

Edit #1: Yes I did try to do it with the e.preventDefault() and it didn't work. However I think I implemented it incorrectly and wasn't really sure what it should look like so I couldn't tell if it was working and not doing what I want or not working at all.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: If you don't mind, could you explain why it needs to be enabled?

Comment: Well I'm working at a page that has some very advanced code populating the drop down list items. And I am required to implement some wordwrapping functionality for this, however it seems that adding this to the DropDownList is not really practical. So I would basically like it to keep the dropdowns the way they are, but when they are clicked have some javascript run to display a pretty menu as opposed to the regular list.

Answer (score 0):

First style the DropDownList unclickable by setting z-index: -1;

```
select {
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Now it will not dropdown anymore. But something like onclick="prettyMenu()" won't work either.

To fix that, wrap a container around the select tag and set the onclick-event for that element:

```
<div onclick="prettyMenu();">
    <select> ... </select>
</div>
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/hgtDe/